# Harmonic functions in the minor scale

Tags: chord-theory, functional-harmony

[image: Chart of chord functions]

The picture above shows that the harmonic functions for chords as:

```
Tonic: I, III, VI
Dominant: V, VII
Subdominant: IV, II
```

Dp these same classification also apply to the natural minor scale?

Comment: Dupe of 'In A natural minor, what are the tonic and sub-dominant family chords?' ?

Comment: There's some odd logic in this image. III is "the relative chord of the dominant function," but there's no mention of III being the relative chord of tonic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. However, chord functions in minor generally assume a raised 7th scale degree (i.e., leading tone). So V in minor is presumed to be a major chord, and VII in minor is presume to be a diminished chord.

When the chords have a lowered seventh (minor V and major VII), although they are generally considered to have the same dominant function, it is a much weaker effect.